# swiftUI is not refresh ui in lower hierarchy

Tags: swiftui

I have a  `@Published  var showDialog: Bool = false` in  viewmodel , once it been true , I want to show a dialog , but for some resone it does not show any , and the same code work if I change showDialog in upper Uis

My Main View

```
 @StateObject  var viewModel = ViewModel.instance


    UploadlingImages( )
     .alert(isPresented: $ViewModel.showDialog) {
      Alert(title:  Text("Content View Alert"),
      message:  Text("Content View Alert"),
    dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
    }
```

---

Code used Inside view , this is as gallery picker

```
struct ImagePickerSwiftUI: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @SwiftUI.Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
   
    @StateObject  var viewModel = ViewModel.instance
    
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerSwiftUI>) -> UIImagePickerController {
     
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator

        return imagePicker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerSwiftUI>) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
     
      return  Coordinator(self)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        var parent: ImagePickerSwiftUI

        init(_ parent: ImagePickerSwiftUI) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
  
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            
           viewModel.showDialog = true // this line in not updateing ui
        
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `@StateObject` only once, in the view that *owns* the view model. That view passes the view model to other views, either as a parameter (and the child views will read it with `@ObservedObject`) or injecting it to the environment, using `.environmentObject()` (and the child views will read it using `@EnvironmentObject`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ViewModel.instance` is shared singleton and `showDialog` is published property, the reason might be in conflict of close/open sheet flows (presentations), so try

```
parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

// delay for previous presentation get closed !!
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
   ViewModel.instance.showDialog = true
}
```